# ASP.NET Web API custom post action not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

So I have a GebruikerController in my API. Gebruiker is dutch for User, what this controller does is that it logs the user in, gets list of users, adds users and get a specific user. But I have encountered a problem when I introduced my own custom post method for a simple login function. Whenever I send some data from PostMan to the function I get the following response:

> {"id":["The value 'login' is not valid."]}

I access it with this url:

> http://localhost:52408/api/gebruikers/login

this is my controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Gebruikers")]
public class GebruikersController : Controller
{
    private readonly flowerpowerContext _context;

    public GebruikersController(flowerpowerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Gebruikers
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Gebruiker> GetGebruiker()
    {
        return _context.Gebruiker;
    }

    // GET: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGebruiker([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var gebruiker = await _context.Gebruiker.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (gebruiker == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(gebruiker);
    }

    [Route("api/gebruikers/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin([FromBody] string email, [FromBody] string password)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if(GebruikerVerify(email, password))
        {
            var gebruiker = await _context.Gebruiker.FirstOrDefaultAsync((g) => (g.GebruikerEmail == email && g.GebruikerWachtwoord == password));
            return Ok(gebruiker);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("invalid data");
        }
    }

    // PUT: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutGebruiker([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Gebruiker gebruiker)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != gebruiker.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(gebruiker).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!GebruikerExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Gebruikers
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostGebruiker([FromBody] Gebruiker gebruiker)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Gebruiker.Add(gebruiker);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetGebruiker", new { id = gebruiker.Id }, gebruiker);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteGebruiker([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var gebruiker = await _context.Gebruiker.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (gebruiker == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Gebruiker.Remove(gebruiker);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(gebruiker);
    }

    private bool GebruikerExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Gebruiker.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    private bool GebruikerVerify(string email, string wacthwoord)
    {
        if(_context.Gebruiker.Any(e => e.GebruikerEmail == email))
        {
            Gebruiker gebruiker = _context.Gebruiker.FirstOrDefault(e => e.GebruikerEmail == email);
            if(wacthwoord == gebruiker.GebruikerWachtwoord)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the following code is my login code, which can also be seen in the code above.

```
        [Route("api/gebruikers/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin([FromBody] string email, [FromBody] string password)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if(GebruikerVerify(email, password))
        {
            var gebruiker = await _context.Gebruiker.FirstOrDefaultAsync((g) => (g.GebruikerEmail == email && g.GebruikerWachtwoord == password));
            return Ok(gebruiker);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("invalid data");
        }
    }

    private bool GebruikerVerify(string email, string wacthwoord)
    {
        if(_context.Gebruiker.Any(e => e.GebruikerEmail == email))
        {
            Gebruiker gebruiker = _context.Gebruiker.FirstOrDefault(e => e.GebruikerEmail == email);
            if(wacthwoord == gebruiker.GebruikerWachtwoord)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm fairly new to this and I'm clueless about what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: routing issue. because of route prefix on controller you are hitting `GetGebruiker` which expects id to be an `int` but it sees  `login`

Comment: next `FromBody` can only be used once in an action parameter. consolidate those parameters into one model and then use the `FromBody` attribute

Comment: You also need to specify which HTTP verb was used when you got the error as `login` is suppose to be a POST request.

Comment: If using a route prefix then there is no need to include the prefix on the action routes.

Comment: so I need to remove the rout and change the FromBody parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a routing issue. Because of route prefix on controller you are hitting `GetGebruiker` which expects `id` to be a `int` but it sees `"login"` string.

Next `FromBody` can only be used once in an action parameter. Consolidate those parameters into one model and then use the `FromBody` attribute.

```
public class LoginModel {
    [Required]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Note the comments used to demonstrate mapped routes.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Gebruikers")]//route prefix for this controller
public class GebruikersController : Controller {
    //...code removed for brevity

    // GET: api/Gebruikers
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Gebruiker> GetGebruiker() {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    // GET: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")] // Note the route constraint
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGebruiker([FromRoute] int id) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    // POST: api/Gebruikers/login
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin([FromBody] LoginModel login) {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if(GebruikerVerify(login.email, login.password)) {
            //...code removed for brevity
        } else {
            return BadRequest("invalid data");
        }
    }

    // PUT: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutGebruiker([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    // POST: api/Gebruikers
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostGebruiker([FromBody] Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    // DELETE: api/Gebruikers/5
    [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteGebruiker([FromRoute] int id) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    //..code removed for brevity
}
```

References

[Routing in ASP.NET Core # Route Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference)

[Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

[Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: ah ok, and I have to send this object:
"login" : [
 {
   "email" : "email@mail.com",
   "password" : "test"
 }
]

if I'm correct?

Comment: @B.Hulshof the object would just be `{ "email" : "email@mail.com", "password" : "test" }`. The model binder would map that to the actio parameter. what you had in your last comment is an array not a single object